# SSH connection with certificate still asking for password

Tags: ssh

Here is the command from the **CLIENT**:

ssh -p 2xxx -vvv -i /home/jxxxxx/.ssh/authorized_keys ixxxxx.com

Here is the pertinent part of the debug info (-vvv):

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/jxxxxx/.ssh/authorized_keys (0x7ff95d1456b0), explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /home/jxxxxx/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
```

Here is info from /var/log/auth.log on the **SERVER**:

`Aug  9 09:11:00 ixxxxx sshd[8200]: Connection closed by xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(CLIENT ip) [preauth]`

Here are the permissions on the **SERVER**:

```
/home/jxxxxx 755
/home/jxxxxx/.ssh 700
/home/jxxxxx/.ssh/id_dsa and id_rsa 600
```

Here are the permissions on the **CLIENT**:

```
/home/jxxxxx 755
/home/jxxxxx/.ssh 700
/home/jxxxxx/.ssh/authorized_keys 600 (contains id_dsa.pub and id_rsa.pub)
```

Pertinent parts of /etc/ssh/sshd_config (SERVER and CLIENT)

```
Port 2xxx
Protocol 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin no
AllowUsers jxxxxx
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes

ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

UsePAM yes
```

Any Suggestions? This is my first query on StackExchange so this is a real stumper for me. None of the other askubuntu questions/answers on this topic are doing the trick.

Comment: `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` is a file on the *server* indicating which keys will be accepted.  The `-i` argument to ssh must be the name of a *private* key file on the local system.  You have the server files on the client and vice versa.

Comment: Have you tried from the client `ssh-copy-id user@server -p 2xxx` command?

Answer (score 4):

Your private key must be on the **client**.  The corresponding public key must be added to an `authorized_keys` file on the **server**.

If your private key is named either `${HOME}/.ssh/id_dsa` or `${HOME}/.ssh/id_rsa`, there is no need for the `-i` option to `ssh`, as it automatically will try these default key names (although it does not hurt if you want to explicitly say you will use the default private key).